# In user descriptor doesn't work pageContext.getOut("<c:import...>")

Tags: java, jsp, taglib, tld

I have a next question. In jsp page I use menu for 2 users ( tutor and student) in dependence on role I choose which from menu files I should include. Smth like this

```
<c:if test="${role eq 'Tutor'}">
                <c:import url="/page/menuForTutor.html" charEncoding="UTF-8"/>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${role eq 'Student'}">
             <c:import url="/page/menuForStudent.html" charEncoding="UTF-8"/>
</c:if>
```

I should use user descriptor

```
public class MenuTag extends TagSupport{

    private static final String PARAM_ROLE_TUTOR = "Tutor";
    private static final String PARAM_ROLE_STUDENT = "Student";

    @Override
    public int doStartTag(){
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)pageContext.
                                                   getRequest();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String role = (String) session.getAttribute("role");
        if (PARAM_ROLE_TUTOR.equals(role)){
            try {
                pageContext.getOut().print("<c:import url=\"/page/menuForTutor.html\" charEncoding=\"UTF-8\"/>");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MenuTag.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } else if(PARAM_ROLE_STUDENT.equals(role)){
        }
        return SKIP_BODY;
    }       
}
```

When I use debag I see that I do all steps but menu for tutor wasn't showed on jsp. Any ideas?

Comment: where have you set "session.putValue("role", PARAM_ROLE_TUTOR);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that session("role") is set in another code part!

set JspWriter   out     = pageContext.getOut();

is something like following in the code

> ```
> JspFactory  factory     = JspFactory.getDefaultFactory();
> PageContext pageContext = factory.getPageContext(
> this,
> request,
> response,
> null,  // errorPageURL
> false, // needsSession
> JspWriter.DEFAULT_BUFFER,
> true   // autoFlush
> );
> ```

```
    ....
            JspWriter   out     = pageContext.getOut();
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            String role = (String) session.getAttribute("role");
            if (PARAM_ROLE_TUTOR.equals(role)){
                try {
                    out.println("<c:import url=\"/page/menuForTutor.html\" charEncoding=\"UTF-8\"/>");
                    out.flush();
                    // Evaluate the body if there is one
                    return EVAL_BODY_BUFFERED;
.......

else return SKIP_BODY;
```

EDIT see code: you have to "return EVAL_BODY_BUFFERED;"

Comment: No, I use pageContext as field class TagSupport. And when I close out I don't on page anything, I think that problem in <с:import>

Comment: and when you call out.flush();

Comment: and when I call out.flash() also. I can print on jsp different numbers and string but othe file doesn't want((

Comment: Sorry use EVAL_BODY_BUFFERED instaed.